# Mapping functions with variable arguments and calling by string c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to have some fair idea how to map functions with variable arguments,return type of int and call it by a string..
Just for an example...

```
int func1(int a, int b);
int func2(int a1, int b1 , int* c1);
int func3(char* dummy);
int func4(double x, long y, int z, char** table);  
int func5(double d1, double b1);  
int func6(int* p, double* q, int i);
```

I just need a common function called

```
int CallFunction("funcname", param1, param2, ...);
```

for example

```
CallFunction("func1", 10, 20); /* calling function func1 and return func1 result*/
```

I know how to map functions using functions pointers having constant arguments but variable arguments seems to be complicated.. could anyone shower some idea how to do it.

I even explored Variadic templates.. But seems to complicated calling functions using strings..

Comment: You mean variable arguements using initializer_list?

Comment: This requires the use of Elven magic. Are you an elf?

Comment: I wonder how you are going to put a `double*` or a `char**` in a string. Anyway, can you show how you are doing it with a fixed number of arguments, say 2?

Answer (score 2):

I had exact the same problem.

Solved it with this solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int func0(int x)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int func1(int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << (x + y) << std::endl;
}

template <class... Args>
struct MapHolder{
    static std::map<std::string, int (*)(Args...)> CallbackMap;
};

template <class... Args>
std::map<std::string, int (*)(Args...)> MapHolder<Args...>::CallbackMap;

class Callback {
public:
    template <class ...Args>
    void RegisterFunction(std::string name, int (*func)(Args...)) { 
        MapHolder<Args...>::CallbackMap[name] = func;
    }

    template <class ...Args>
    int ExecuteFunction(std::string name, Args &&... args) { 
        return MapHolder<Args...>::CallbackMap[name](std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Callback cb;

    cb.RegisterFunction("func0", &func0);
    cb.RegisterFunction("func1", &func1);

    cb.ExecuteFunction("func0", 42);
    cb.ExecuteFunction("func1", 42, 42);
    return 0;
}
```

This snippet is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044150/a-map-of-functions-with-variadic-signatures-in-c?answertab=votes#tab-top). I only use other class/function names.

Comment: this is beautiful answer! I wonder if it can be improved by using std::function?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but anyway...

### 1. Creating a generic value holder

[boost.any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html) didn't make it into the standard, and, in case you don't know what it is, it allows you to store any C++ value in a single type (`any`) and get it back if you know the type. The following is a toy implementation of it:

```
struct TypeHandler {
    void* (*copyFrom)(void *src);
    void (*destroy)(void *p);
};

template<typename T>
TypeHandler *thandler() {
    struct THandler {
        static void *copyFrom(void *p) { return new T(*(T *)p); }
        static void destroy(void *p) { delete (T *)p; }
    };
    static TypeHandler th = { &THandler::copyFrom, &THandler::destroy };
    return &th;
}
```

`TypeHandler` contains two pointer to functions that know how to copy and how to destroy a specific C++ type. A `Value` can hold any type because it's composed of a `void *` and a pointer to a `TypeHandler`. When copying or destroying is required on the instance it asks to the specific type handler function...

```
struct Value {
    TypeHandler *th;
    void *p;

    Value(const Value& other) : th(other.th), p(th->copyFrom(other.p)) { }
    template<typename T> Value(const T& x) : th(thandler<T>()), p(new T(x)) { }
    ~Value() { th->destroy(p); }

    Value& operator=(const Value& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            th->destroy(p);
            th = other.th;
            p = th->copyFrom(other.p);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Value& operator=(const T& other) {
        th->destroy(p);
        th = thandler<T>();
        p = new T(other);
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    T& to() const {
        if (th != thandler<T>()) throw Error("type mismatch");
        return *(T*)p;
    }
};
```

Note that `Value` is copyable and can be passed by value and can be returned by functions.
Any copyable object is implicitly convertible into a `Value` and I can also convert it back to the original type with `to<T>()`.

### 2. Creating the name->function maps

```
std::map<std::string, Value (*)(const Value&)> map1;
std::map<std::string, Value (*)(const Value&, const Value&)> map2;

Value call(const std::string& name, const Value& x1) {
    return map1.at(name)(x1);
}

Value call(const std::string& name, const Value& x1, const Value& x2) {
    return map2.at(name)(x1, x2);
}
```

Here I've created explicit maps for 1 and 2 arguments. May be this can be done using C++11 variadic templates, I didn't try. In C++03 libraries it's common to see this kind of stuff copy-n-pasted up to say n=20 to cover reasonable cases.

### 3. Macrology

To simplify registration of functions I wrote two ugly macros. May be this can be done also using variadic macros or templates (I'm not so sure about it, especially the automatic registration of the wrapper in the map).

```
#define regfunc1(name, t1)                   \
    Value name(const Value& x1) {            \
        return name(x1.to<t1>());            \
    }                                        \
    struct name##_ {                         \
        name##_() { map1[#name]=&name; }     \
    } name##_instance

#define regfunc2(name, t1, t2)                           \
    Value name(const Value& x1, const Value& x2) {       \
        return name(x1.to<t1>(), x2.to<t2>());           \
    }                                                    \
    struct name##_ {                                     \
        name##_() { map2[#name]=&name; }                 \
    } name##_instance
```

### 4. Use

```
double square(double x) {
    return x*x;
}

double hyp2(double x, double y) {
    return x*x+y*y;
}

int mylen(const std::string& s) {
    return s.size();
}


regfunc1(square, double);
regfunc2(hyp2, double, double);
regfunc1(mylen, std::string);

int main() {
    Value x = 42;
    Value y = std::string("This is a test");
    Value z = 3.14;
    printf("%0.3f\n", call("square", z).to<double>());
    printf("%0.3f\n", call("hyp2", z, z).to<double>());
    printf("mylen(\"%s\") = %i\n",
           y.to<std::string>().c_str(),
           call("mylen", y).to<int>());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hi.. Can I make a map with string and a void function pointer ? This is just my logic not tested...say like this...
`typedef int (*TFPfunc1)(int, int );
typedef int (*TFPfunc2)(int , int , int* );
TFPfunc1 FPfunc1 = &func1;
TFPfunc2 FPfunc2 = &func2;
typedef int (*GenericFuncP)();
std::map<std::string, GenericFuncP)> MainMap;
MainMap["func1"] = (TFPfunc1) FPfunc1;
MainMap["func2"] = (TFPfunc2) FPfunc2;`

Comment: @Lo1234: Yes the standard allows casting a function pointer to a different function pointer type, provided you cast it back to the proper function pointer type before using it. Note that instead casting a function pointer to a `void *` and back is not guaranteed to work (function pointers and data pointers may be of different size). The statement should however be `MainMap["func1"]=(GenericFuncP)FPFunc1;` to work and you should convert it back to `TFPfunc1` before using it.

Comment: Hi thanks.. the logic is working but can you tell me any idea how to dynamically cast it TFPfunc1 by string "func1" if passed? say if I pass "Func1" it should typecast to TFPfunc1, If I pass "Func2" it should typecast to TFPfunc2.... any idea please? any trick?

Comment: @Lo1234: The only way is to store the number of arguments and make a `switch(...)` or similar. In C/C++ there's no portable way to call dynamically a function building the argument list (what is available is passing around variable list like for `printf`, but doesn't work for C++ objects and you cannot call a function that expects a fixed number of arguments that way).