# How to pass variable arguments to Variadic template function in a right way C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Hi I got a variadic templates in C++

```
int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
auto MainCall(Func func, Args&&... args)-> typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type
{
    return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename... Args>
int call2(Args const&... args)
{
    return MainCall(sum, args...); /* calling template function MainCall,  
                                      how to pass the variable arguments to   
                                      Maincall from here?
                                   */
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  cout << call2(4,5) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Am I doing a right way of passing arguments? I get the compiler error like this
**error C3520: 'args' : parameter pack must be expanded in this context**
**see reference to function template instantiation 'int call2(const int &,const int &)' being compiled**

What is the correct way of passing variable arguments to the MainCall template?

**Note:
    Parameters need to be always variable so that MainCall can take any function with any number of arguments.. Just for an example I have writen sum function here..**

Comment: What version of VisualStudio are you using? VS2013 Update 4, and gcc, both [compile and run](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae55cb82bbbe84d6) your code correctly. Unrelated to your error, but don't you want to perfectly forward the arguments to `call2()` also?

Comment: What you have here will compile and run once presented with the conveniently omitted `#include` list on clang. It will *not* compile for more, or less, than two arguments. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Praetorian:Yes you were right I have visual studio 2012 I tried to reinstall the C++ compiler strange now it works... I am trying to create template which takes name of the function as a string and arguments as its type..I have asked the question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670222/mapping-functions-with-variable-arguments-and-calling-by-string-c)... I was just playing around with the templates to achieve that. Moreover the arguments does support only upto 5... passing more than 5 arguments it gives compiler error

Comment: I didn't even know VS2012 supported variadic templates. I thought its stdlib supported some faux varidiac template like behavior through the use of x-macros. Anyway, you might be able to increase that limit by defining `VARIADIC_MAX` (or something similar) to a larger number.

Comment: `
template<typename... funcname, typename... Args>
int CallFunction(const std::string& funcname , Args&&... args)
{
 
 if(!funcname.compare("sum"))
 {
  return MainCall(sum, args...);
 }
 else if(!funcname.compare("sum"))
 {
  return MainCall(size, args...);
 }
 else
 {
  return 0;
 }
}`
I am getting error `error C2197: 'int (__cdecl *)(char *)' : too many arguments for call`
`see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Result_type<false,_Fty,_V0_t,_V0_t,_V2_t,_V2_t,_V4_t,_V4_t,_V6_t,_V6_t,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>' being compiled`

Comment: when I try to call from main function like this `cout << CallFunction("sum",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) << endl;`

Comment: size function is nothing but 
`int size(char* str)   { strcpy(str,"HI"); return 1; }`