# Proper way of using Variadic template function call with string arguments c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello what wrong Iam doing here in using variadic templates via string?
How to use it properly to achieve the below task?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

int sum(int a, int b, int c, int d) { return a+b+c+d; }
int strcopy(char* str)   { strcpy(str,"Hello World!!!"); return 1; }

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
auto MainCall(Func func, Args&&... args)-> typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type
{
    return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename... funcname, typename... Args>
int CallFunction(std::string const& Func , Args&&... args)
{

    if(!Func.compare("sum"))
    {
        return MainCall(sum, args...);
    }
    else if(!Func.compare("strcopy"))
    {
        return MainCall(strcopy, args...);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char buffer[512];
    cout <<  CallFunction("sum",1,2,3,4) << end1; /* How to properly execute "sum" function by sending string name to variadic function template function??? */
    CallFunction("strcopy",buffer); /* How to properly execute "strcopy" function by sending string name to variadic function template function??? */
    printf("Buffer says = %s" , buffer); /* Should print "Hello World!!!" */
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I get compiler error like
 **error C2197: 'int (__cdecl *)(char *)' : too many arguments for Maincall**
**`see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Result_type<false,_Fty,_V0_t,_V0_t,_V2_t,_V2_t,_V4_t,_V4_t,_V6_t,_V6_t,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>' being compiled`**

Comment: Please improve your old question, instead of asking the same again.

Comment: I'm not into C++, maybe it's expected, but I don't see your call to `MainCall`. Also, try to remove anything until remove anything more makes the bug disappear. i.e does it still happen when you remove the call to the "sum" ? The printf ? getchar()... etc. We only need the strictly necessary code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: This is totally different question from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701828/how-to-pass-variable-arguments-to-variadic-template-function-in-a-right-way-c)... Here I want to know how to use variadic template using string and calling a function. Yes !!! I have asked this question in that post in comments column since I didnt get any answer I posted it has new question.

Comment: @Lo1234 Well, patience is a gift.

Comment: @Lo1234 you didn't get any answer on your previous question because your code worked fine. You admitted to using an old compiler which didn't support variadic templates and after upgrading it you were able to successfully run your code. What answer do you expect on that question now?

Comment: @bolov Can you please compare both the code?? I think the questions are not same. I have just improvised the code and I got stuck. This question is nowhere related to my old question as I have already explained above

Comment: @Lo1234 Yes I see now that it is not the same question. My previous point remains valid: your previous question doesn't have an answer.

Comment: @bolov That problem got solved by reinstalling the C++11 compiler.. that was the answer given by me in the comments column

Answer (score 3):

The problem is:

When you call:

```
CallFunction("sum", 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The templated function `CallFunction` is instantiated with `funcanme={}` (totally useless, you can remove it) and  `Args={int, int, int, int}`. In this function you have a line: `MainCall(strcopy, args...);` which in this case becomes: `MainCall(strcopy, 1, 2, 3, 4)` which in turn calls `strcopy(1, 2, 3, 4)` which is invalid call.

There is no (non-convoluted) way in C++ to call function with different prototypes based on a name known at runtime and taking a variadic argument pack.

Comment: Thank you.. Is there any alternative way similar to this to achieve this concept?

Comment: @Lo1234 I guess you could do something with `constexpr` functions that map a string to an id, and then have specialized templates for each id/ prototype, but even if that would be doable (highly unlikely) it would be too convoluted and too much hassle for something that I don't see any practical advantages. Stick to using function pointers and not function names (string).