# A map of functions with variadic signatures in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, factory-pattern

From

> Martin Reddy's API Design for C++ - Chapter 3 (section 3.3.3
>   Extensible Factory Example)

I found this implementation of Factory pattern to be pretty efficient which allows a user to register callback functions (essentially constructors for the derived classes) at run time, which can eventually be called when creating an object of that type. The code is shown below, as taken from the textbook -

File : rendererfactory.h

```
class RendererFactory
{
public:
    typedef IRenderer *(*CreateCallback)();
    static void RegisterRenderer(const std::string &type, CreateCallback cb);
    static void UnregisterRenderer(const std::string &type);
    static IRenderer *CreateRenderer(const std::string &type);
private:
    typedef std::map<std::string, CreateCallback> CallbackMap;
    static CallbackMap mRenderers;
};
```

File : rendererfactory.cpp

```
#include "rendererfactory.h"

// instantiate the static variable in RendererFactory
RendererFactory::CallbackMap RendererFactory::mRenderers;

void RendererFactory::RegisterRenderer(const std::string &type, CreateCallback cb)
{
    mRenderers[type] = cb;
}

void RendererFactory::UnregisterRenderer(const std::string &type)
{
    mRenderers.erase(type);
}

IRenderer *RendererFactory::CreateRenderer(const std::string &type)
{
    CallbackMap::iterator it = mRenderers.find(type);
    if (it != mRenderers.end())
    {
        // call the creation callback to construct this derived type
        return (it->second)();
    }
    return NULL;
}

class UserRenderer : public IRenderer
{
public:
    ~UserRenderer() {}
    static IRenderer *Create() { return new UserRenderer(); }
};
```

File : main.cpp

```
int main(int, char **)
{
    // register a new renderer
    RendererFactory::RegisterRenderer("user", UserRenderer::Create);

    // create an instance of our new renderer
    IRenderer *r = RendererFactory::CreateRenderer("user");

    r->Render();

    delete r;

    return 0;
}
```

My limitation with this code is that it assumes are constructors of derived objects, do not take any arguments. For instance if I had a derived class -

```
class UserRendererMultiArgs : public IRenderer
{
public:
    UserRendererMultiArgs(int, int);
    ~UserRendererMultiArgs() {}
    static IRenderer *Create() { 
        return new UserRendererMultiArgs(); //Incorrect : need to call UserRendererMultiArgs(int, int) ??? 
    }
};
```

How would I go about achieving the same results of registering callback with variable arguments in the map maintained by the RendererFactory class?

I have though of using varargs but I am not sure how to do it ?!

Comment: Where should the arguments for the callback come from?

Comment: They come from the client when calling CreateRenderer(...). I am thinking I can change that call to take variadic arguments.

Comment: That would require examination of the arguments (number or arguments, types) at runtime, which is not possible. Also note that plain _new_ and _delete_ should not be used in C++ and _NULL_  should be replaced with _nullptr_. Use _std::unique_ptr_ instead.

Comment: The code is picked up from the text book but yes I do agree that all those things are deprecated. Can you tell me how I can achieve that ?

Comment: Passing types to functions is possible by using templates, but that's a compile-time feature. For what you want requires the _CreateRenderer_-function to be able to check whether the provided arguments do match the arguments expected by the callback and then somehow pass them. But the function doesn't know the expected number and types of arguments at comple-time.

Comment: Compile time would be fine too. Can you provide a snippet of how I can do this ?

Comment: It isn't possible at all.

Comment: If you value your sanity you should change how you handle memory. Raw new/delete with raw owning pointers is not sustainable. Consider using `std::unique_ptr` to avoid having to worry about memory management.

Comment: I already noted that ;)

Comment: Can it not be done with variadic functions ? Provided the Create() function for every derived class would know how to parse the argument list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the factory pattern and going with the title of the question then this might do what you want:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct IRenderer {};

class UserRendererMultiArgs : public IRenderer {
    public:
    UserRendererMultiArgs(int, int) {}
    ~UserRendererMultiArgs() {}
    static IRenderer *Create(int i1, int i2) {
        return new UserRendererMultiArgs(i1, i2);
    }
};

template <class... Args>
struct MapHolder{
    static std::map<std::string, IRenderer *(*)(Args...)> CallbackMap;
};

template <class... Args>
std::map<std::string, IRenderer *(*)(Args...)> MapHolder<Args...>::CallbackMap;

class RendererFactory {
    public:
    template <class... Args>
    static void RegisterRenderer(std::string name, IRenderer *(*Callback)(Args...)) {
        MapHolder<Args...>::CallbackMap[name] = Callback;
    }

    template <class... Args>
    static IRenderer *Create(const std::string &name, Args &&... args) {
        return MapHolder<Args...>::CallbackMap[name](std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

int main() {
    RendererFactory::RegisterRenderer("user", &UserRendererMultiArgs::Create);
    std::unique_ptr<IRenderer> r{RendererFactory::Create("user", 42, 3)};
}
```

([demo to play with](https://ideone.com/JRkC8M))

In C++14 you have variable templates to not need that `MapHolder`, but the tag specified C++11.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. I had a hard time framing the question right but am glad you could make some sense of it :D. I will try this out !

Comment: Also just for reference how would the code differ if I were using C++14. How would variable templates replace the need for MapHolder ?

Comment: @nitimalh You would use `template <class... Args> std::map<std::string, IRenderer *(*)(Args...)> CallbackMap;` to declare it and `CallbackMap<Args...>` to access it. Not a big difference, just a bit nicer syntax. If you intend to use this you should sprinkle some `std::remove_cv` and `std::remove_reference` around so that `int`, `const int`, `int &` and so on are treated as the same type as far as callback lookup is concerned.

Comment: Just a follow up to your solution. If I do this in my `main()` function
`RendererFactory::RegisterRenderer("user", &UserRendererMultiArgs::Create);

int i = 42;

std::unique_ptr<IRenderer> r{RendererFactory::Create("user", i, 3)};`
 I get a segmentation fault. Why is that ?

Comment: @nitimalh That is because `42` will be deduced as a `int &&` whereas `i` is deduced to be a `int &`. Because of that a different `CallbackMap` is used, which doesn't have the function saved, so you get a default constructed function pointer which is a `nullptr`. That is what I meant with `remove_cv` above, you want `int &`, `int &&`, `const volatile int &` and so on to be in the same category `int`.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. However, I am not sure where and how to add remove_cv/reference ?!

Comment: @nitimalh Turns out the `remove_cv_ref`-part was more difficult than anticipated. The problem is that the parameters of the function are also parameters of the map, so to find the map we have to restore the original arguments exactly. We cannot just remove the cv-ref because then the map cannot store the function pointers because the types don't match. We can either restore the types by making you type them out when you call `Create` (use `RendererFactory::Create<int, int>(i, 3)`, which sucks) or we just don't allow cv-ref-qualified types in the callbacks (also sucks). The first ...

Comment: ... solution works out of the box. The second one you can find [here](https://ideone.com/Yx4FzQ). If you have further questions ping me in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116940/c-questions-and-answers) since discussions in comments don't work so well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will go through your provided solution and see if I can make sense of it. Really appreciate your help. Will ping you if I need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the arguments at compile time you can use

```
RendererFactory::RegisterRenderer("multiuser", []{
    return new UserRendererMultiArgs(1, 2);
});
```

If you do not know the arguments at compile time you can use

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
std::cin >> i >> j;
RendererFactory::RegisterRenderer("multiuser", [i, j]{
    return new UserRendererMultiArgs(i, j);
});
```

However, now that the lambda carries state it cannot be assigned to a function pointer anymore, so you would need to change the type of `CreateCallback` to `std::function<IRenderer *()>` which incurs some cost due to dynamic memory allocations required to capture arbitrarily sized function objects.

Comment: I think he was asking for extending the _CreateRenderer_-method to accept various arguments.

Comment: @TheTechel In that case I don't understand the question anymore. First we throw away type information with that pattern to treat all types the same, then we treat the types differently trying to recover the type information. One of these is not desired. ImNot clarify?

Comment: yeah, his design is a bit weird.